# How to roast a chicken in a hotel room

Tags: food, food-safety

Is there a way to roast a *whole* chicken in your own hotel room? Let's assume that the hotel provides you with some standard things like towels, iron/ironing board, minibar fridge, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure no hotels will allow this. Smoke detectors can go off when you attempt such a thing. If at all you want to attempt this, go to the hotel room balcony, get an open grill and do your business. Make sure you are extra careful with the whole procedure. No other appliance provided by the hotel can be used. And using an Iron box is totally inadvisable as you may spoil the iron box as well as ending up with an under-cooked chicken. Having said all that, the whole idea is inappropriate and dangerous and I think you should not do it. Order in, maybe; or ask the reception where you can do it yourself...maybe they will provide you with the area and materials needed for the same.

Comment: There are rotisserie convection ovens that can do this that hotels (especially extended stay types) might reasonably provide, but I don't know of any chains that do this.  You might check with their reservation staff before booking your stay -- but you probably won't find such appliances, even in extended stay, because of the tiny kitchen space and thus limited number of specialty appliances provided.